# Error Message in survfit data frame to produce survival plots in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Getting this error when attempting to run my code: `Error in model.frame.default(data = list(an = c(0, 0), gn = c(0, 0), pkd = c(0, : variable lengths differ (found for 'age.c')`

Here is my code:

```
library(KMsurv)
library(survival)
data(kidrecurr)
attach(kidrecurr)
head(kidrecurr)
#Long Form
kid.dat <- data.frame(patient=rep(patient, 2), time=c(time1, time2), infect=c(infect1, infect2), age=age, gender=gender, gn=gn, an=an, pkd=pkd)

kid.surv <- Surv(kid.dat$time, kid.dat$infect)
age.c <- kid.dat$age-mean(kid.dat$age)
#Cox ph
kid.ph <- coxph(kid.surv~kid.dat$an+kid.dat$gn+kid.dat$pkd+kid.dat$gender+age.c)
#Frailty Model
kid.f <- coxph(kid.surv~kid.dat$an+kid.dat$gn+kid.dat$pkd+kid.dat$gender+age.c+frailty(kid.dat$patient, dist="gamma"))
#Marginal Model
kid.m <- coxph(kid.surv~kid.dat$an+kid.dat$gn+kid.dat$pkd+kid.dat$gender+age.c+cluster(kid.dat$patient))

#Summaries for confidence intervals, hazard ratios, and p-values
summary(kid.ph)
summary(kid.f)
summary(kid.m)

#Plot of survivals for gender for each model

newdat <- data.frame(an=0, gn=0, pkd=0, gender=0:1, age.c=0); newdat
fit.ph <- survfit(kid.ph, newdat)
fit.m <- survfit(kid.m, newdat)
##Frailty model items for plot
modf.bh <- basehaz(kid.f)
modf.surv0f25 <- exp(-modf.bh$hazard*.25)
modf.surv1f25 <- exp(-modf.bh$hazard*.25)^exp(kid.f$coef)
```

My goal is to produce a single plot of the estimated survival functions for males and females from the coxph models, frailty model, and marginal model. However, I am getting this error and cannot get the rest to work.
Any help is appreciated! I am not sure what the issue is. I understand that the dataframe should just be one line for each of the gender levels and the rest is "zeroed" out, which I have in my data.frame.
I have tried amending the age variable to have 0 for 76 entries and then gender repeating, but this does not create the plot that I need (multiple survival lines).

Comment: don't use `$` in a formula, your code should look like this `coxph(kid.surv ~ an + gn + pkd + gender + age.c, kid.dat)` then it will work

Comment: @rawr Wow! that makes a lot of since and I believe that fixed it. Thanks so much! I spent so much time trying to figure it out.